# bootstrap5 sidebar appears above the block content, how to make it sticky-left

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I made a Django blog with bootstrap5, following the advice from the python crash-course book.
All of my templates extend base.html where I have code like below.
The problem is that whatever I try, it always goes above, between, or under my block contents, I don't know how to "override" my blocks and stick my sidebar to the left. Under the code, I'll post images with my little paint visualization. The upper one is how it is right now, and the second how I want it to be.

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <!--thats sticky top navbar i'll skip this cause it work good -->
  </nav>
       <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row w-50 flex-column flex-md-row">
                <aside class="col-12 col-md-3 col-xl-2 p-0 bg-dark flex-shrink-1">
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md sticky-start navbar-dark bd-dark
                    flex-md-column flex-row align-items-center py-2 text-center" id="sidebar">
                        <div class="text-center p-3">
                            <img src="..." alt="profile picture" class="img-fluid rounded-circle my-4 p-1 d-none d-md-block shadow">
                            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand mx-0 font-weight-bold text-nowrap">RETOVSKEJ</a>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler border-0 order-1"
                                data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav" aria-controls="nav"
                                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-last" id="nav">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav flex-column w-100 justify-content-center">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#" class="nav-link active">Edit profile</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Projects</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                </aside>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            {% block header %}{% endblock header %}
            {% block content %}{% endblock content %}
        </div>
</body>
```

[image: how it is]

[image: how i want it to be]

thanks for every help.

Comment: I'm using flask with bootstrap5 and having the exact same problem. My sidebars will take exactly one screen not content on the rightside. Then my content will appear after i scroll down. I'll let you know once i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
style="postion: fixed; margin-top: 300px;"
```

in

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

worked.